# Apache rewrite condition on SSL certificate error

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, redirect

I am trying to configure my apache(v2.4.23) in Ubuntu, so that if SSL certificate fails https page will redirect to a custom error page.

In various web pages solution is given with rewrite condition and rules as following.

```
<Location /login/>
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth 3
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
        RewriteRule .* /login_error/ [L]
</Location>
```

Unfortunately I still couldn't make this solution work for me and can't achieve redirection on certificate error. I just get standard browser error page "ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT".

What can be missing or misconfigured in my apache configuration file?

NOTE: I tested these following configurations for testing.

This one redirects to login_error as expected:

```
<Location /login/>
        #SSLVerifyClient optional
        #SSLVerifyDepth 3
        #SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

        RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
        RewriteRule .* /login_error/ [L]
</Location>
```

This one doesn't redirect, too:

```
<Location /login/>
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth 3
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

        RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
        RewriteRule .* /login_error/ [L]
</Location>
```

So after enabling "**SSLVerifyClient optional**"  rewrite loose effect.(I tried SSLVerifyClient with optional_no_ca, doesn't work either.)

Comment: It’s called HTTP _over_ SSL/TLS for a reason. If the client doesn’t like your TLS setup (for example due to a missing or invalid certificate), then it will not even get to the point where your client and server start talking HTTP to each other. So you can not perform any HTTP redirects.

Comment: I get it and I don't get it. Why some people show it as a solution to their problem then?

Comment: Dunno, maybe different problems ...

Comment: Maybe this helps? --> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrenegbuffersize  ----> If an SSL renegotiation is required in per-location context, for example, any use of SSLVerifyClient in a Directory or Location block, then mod_ssl must buffer any HTTP request body into memory until the new SSL handshake can be performed. This directive can be used to set the amount of memory that will be used for this buffer.

Comment: As a workaround you can just exchange ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT.var for your custom SSL_errorpage and rename it to ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT.VAR.....but that's pretty dirty^^